# Mat expansion panel's toggle icon disappears when it is disabled

Tags: angular, angular-material

Mat expansion panel's toggle icon disappears when it is disabled. I want the icon to remain there but the functionality would be disabled. how do i do it???

tried hideToggle="false", doesnt work.

**html file:**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [disabled]="isOnPageTwo" hideToggle="false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

only disable when the boolean isOnPageTwo is true. Like I said, I want the toggle icon to appear there even when disabled. By default the toggle icon is removed when disabled is applied. Thanks...

Comment: Can you add the sample code for the same?it will be helpful to fix your issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.